# Как получить значение из атрибута data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image]

Нужно было получить данные из атрибута data-user_id

```
$('.submit_button').click(function () {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url:'/../title/comment',
            type:'post',
            data: {
                'comment_text': $('#comment_area').val(),
                'title_id' : $(this).data('title_id'),
            },
            success:function (data) {
                if (data != "u're guest")
                    if (data !='update')
                  $('#comment_area').prepend(data);
                else {
                        alert($('.submit_button').data('user_id'));
                        )
                    }
                else alert('Чтобы оставлять комментарии войдите в профиль');
                //Checking if user is logged in
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Выводится undefined, при том, что значения из атрибута title_id получить удаётся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До запроса сохраните текущий элемент (`$(this)`) в переменную, и уже в запросе в место `$(this)` используете ту переменную, а `user_id` вы получаете потому что не используете `$(this)` а сразу выбираете элемент с классом (`$('.submit_button').data('user_id')`).

```js
$('.submit_button').click(function() {
        var this_button = $(this);
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/../title/comment',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        'comment_text': $('#comment_area').val(),
                        'title_id': this_button.data('title_id'),
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        console.log(this_button.data('title_id'));
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data != "u're guest")
                            if (data != 'update')
                                $('#comment_area').prepend(data);
                            else {
                                alert($('.submit_button').data('user_id'));
                            }
                        else
                            alert('Чтобы оставлять комментарии войдите в профиль');
                    }
                }
        )
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="submit_button" data-title_id="title_idd" data-user_id="xxx">click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```
let element = document.getElementByClassName('submit_button')[0]; //получаем элемент по классу
let result = element.getAttribute('data-user_id');
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
$('.submit_button').click(function(){
   alert($(this).data('title_id'));
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button class="submit_button" data-title_id="title_idd" data-user_id="xxx">click</button>
```

var user_id = $(this).data('user_id');

Как-то так. Пардон, моя ошибка data не учитывается... Этот код отработает...

Comment: Почитаете вот эту статью `https://habrahabr.ru/post/139210/`, и документацию `https://api.jquery.com/data/`. И совет если наверняка не знаете что ответ правильный не дайте ответ, что бы не ввести в заблуждение человека задавшего вопрос.

Comment: для начала проверьте код, а потом критикуйте...Вы еще наверное пользуетесь версией 1.3 по этому и не работает...

Comment: Проверил и без `ajax` запроса ответ `undefined`.

Comment: Проверьте......

Comment: Ну да вот так работать будет, а вы писали `$(this).data('data-user_id');`. Это и `$(this).data('user_id');` разные вещи.